# Interrupt a Java Thread from outside the program on Linux

Tags: java, linux, multithreading, interrupt

In our Java application (more precisely a WAR running in Tomcat), a Thread is sometimes waiting a long time for network communication or similar, with `Socket.read(...)`. An example are operations with the Java Mail library, if the connection/read/write timeouts are not set.

Since this can be a problem on production, and a quick deployment is sometimes not an option:

**Question:** 
Is it possible (and how) *on Linux* to "force" an interrupt for *a specific thread* from *outside* the program (meaning, without modifying the existing application) - like with a debugger, OS signal to the process, or similar.

The thread must not be killed - I just need to make sure that Java throws the "Interrupted Exception" from the method it currently is blocked in.

Comment: You can't pass `OS signals` just like to the processes. Are you aware the process has a handler for each of the signals? How does one know which signal to pass to?

Comment: Very simply you could pass `SIGINT` to the thread, if you know its id

Comment: @Inian I'm not sure if it is possible at all! Our process is a java application (more precisely, a WAR running in Tomcat). What happens if I use SIGINT - will Java just terminate (unwanted)?

Comment: As you are already in a Tomcat environment just extend your WAR by code that manages all created threads and provides an authenticated web UI for interrupting one or many threads manually.

Comment: True @Inian, but I am explicitly looking for a way *without* changing the existing application (since it is already deployed).